# JavaScript inheritance with jQuery - calling parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, inheritance, parent

Is there a better method for merging two objects and calling parent functions?

```
var a = {
   a:1,
   myFunction:function(){
       console.info("a");
   }
}

var b = {
    b:2,
    myFunction:function(){
        console.info("b");
        this.callParent();
    }
}

var obj = {};
$.extend(obj, a);
$.extend(obj, b);
b = obj;
b.superclass = a;
```

wrapping all functions so "this.callParent" is present

```
function wrap(func, parent) {
    return function() {
        this.callParent = parent;
        var result = func.apply(this, arguments);
        return (this.callParent), result;
    };
}
```

with an iteration such as:

```
$.each(b, function(key, value){
        if(typeof value == "function" && b.superclass && b.superclass[key]){
            b[key] = wrap(value, b.superclass[key]);
        }
});
```

with an output "b -> a":

```
b.myFunction();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5vyp7/)

Comment: jQuery in general and `$.extend();` would not be related to inheritance in JavaScript. All `$.extend()` does is merge 2 objects it does not care much for the `prototype` or the `prototype.constructor` nor would `$.extend(objA, objB)` cause `objA instanceof objB` to be true. Saying *JavaScript inheritance with jQuery* is very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better method for merging two objects and calling parent functions?

Yes, doing it in one step with a single helper function, instead of that flubbed way with `$.extend`.

Notice that jQuery's `extend` function does not really set up any inheritance, it just can be used for mixins - you shouldn't use the term "inheritance" within reference to that. Also, your objects `a` and `b` are definitely no "classes", so please don't name it `.superclass`. They're singletons at best.

You can do inheritance in the way you suggested, but notice it is not *prototypical inheritance* as one would expect in JavaScript.

```
function inheritObject(parent, child) {
    for (var p in parent)
        if (!(p in child))
            child[p] = parent[p]; // extend
        else if (typeof child[p] == "function") (function(name, fn) {
            child[name] = function() { // inherit
                this.callParent = parent[name];
                var res = fn.apply(this, arguments);
                delete this.callParent;
                return res;
            };
        }(p, child[p]));
    return child;
}
```

```
var a = {
   a:1,
   myFunction:function(){
       console.info("a");
   }
}

var b = inheritObject(a, {
    b:2,
    myFunction:function(){
        console.info("b");
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```